# Sending an email about thread groups in JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

Very new to JMeter and I've just written a script that will test enquiry forms on our sites. Each site has its own thread and the test for their enquiry forms is inside the corresponding thread.

Is there a way to send 1 email after the test has completed with the status of each thread group? i.e thread group 1 passed, thread group 2 passed, thread group 3 failed, thread group 4 passed etc.. The idea is that this script will run once a week automatically and if one of the sites has an error then I'll be notified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently do you create some kind of report in any format?

If yes, JMeter has a SMTP sampler which you could use it in a tear down thread group to send the report to the given email addresses.

You mentioned that you run this periodically. If you use jenkins or other CI tools, that may be configured to send the results.

This might give some idea.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part2/

Comment: Thanks, this has helped a lot!